# How are praying times handled in countries with a long day light?

Tags: prayer-timings

Since praying times are based on the sun position, I was wondering how they are handled in countries like Finland where the days or nights are very long depending on the time of the year.

Comment: Off the cuff-answer: you might be praying the night prayer at 11:30 and the morning prayer at 2:30 (Edmonton, for example). Is that what you're asking, or are you asking about the north pole (six months of day, six months of night)?

Comment: I was referring to polar regions. where the sun doesn't set for several months.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Good question! This is at least one [scholarly answer](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/5842) to the question:

> Whoever lives in a land in which the sun does not set during the
>   summer and does not rise during the winter, or who lives in a land in
>   which the day lasts for six months and the night lasts for six months,
>   for example, has to perform the five daily prayers in each twenty-four
>   hour period. They should estimate their times based on the nearest
>   country in which the times of the five daily prayers can be
>   distinguished from one another

Here is another answer from a [moon sighting website](http://moonsighting.com/faq_pt.html#G3):

> Polar regions like Norway, Finland, and Alaska have areas where the
>   sun stays below horizon for several months in winter, and stays above
>   horizon for several months in summer. However, there comes a time in
>   every day when the sun is at its highset point (Noon) and at lowest
>   point (Midnight). At temperate latitudes, the highest point is visible
>   but lowest point is below horizon. But at higher latitudes (Polar
>   region, like Norway, Finland, and Alaska) the highest and lowest point
>   occur below horizon in winter (meaning several months long night), and
>   above horizon in summer when the sun never sets for several months
>   (meaning several months long day). But we can calculate those two
>   points and determine Prayer times around those two known times every
>   day.

Comment: I think her question may be about places where night-time is just a few hours as well. +1 good reference

Answer (score 10):

> ...We said: Allah's Messenger, would one day's prayer suffice for the
>   prayers of day equal to one year? Thereupon he said: No, but you must
>   make an estimate of time (and then observe prayer)... ([Sahih Muslim 41:7015](http://www.cmje.org/religious-texts/hadith/muslim/041-smt.php#041.7015))

Although the above hadith was reported regarding the time of *Al-Dajjal*, wherein he will walk the earth for forty days, one day like a year, one day like a month, and one day like a week, the ruling made by the prophet in this exchange can also be applied to the so-called "Lands of the Midnight Sun", where the sun literally does not set for days or months at a time.

I know of no hadiths explaining exactly how one is supposed to "make an estimate of time", but two major interpretations I am aware of are as follows:

1. Pray according to the times used by the nearest location in which the times of prayer can still be discerned in the traditional way (i.e., by the position of the sun),
2. Pray according to the clock, using the prayer times of Mecca.

---

As for those countries in which the times of prayer can still be determined according to the position of the sun, but in which said times are highly inconvenient due to the sun setting extremely late and rising extremely early during the summer, or vice-versa during the winter, I know of no reason that the same ruling could not be applied. The above report suggests that the exact times of the prayers (in relation to the position of the sun) is less important than the fact that they are still performed regularly.

Alternatively, joining prayers (such as joining the Maghrib and Isha prayers so they are performed at the same time) is another option, as the prophet is reported to have done the same so as to make things easier for his followers ([Sahih Muslim 4:1516](http://www.cmje.org/religious-texts/hadith/muslim/004-smt.php#004.1516)).

Comment: Wouldn't an estimate of time be the regular day's routines? Like waking up, starting work, eating lunch, ending work, eating dinner, relax, sleep.

Comment: @jason That's one possible interpretation, yes. There was a fatwa to that effect making the rounds last Ramadan (from the UK, I believe) but to the best of my knowledge it's not a particularly mainstream interpretation.

Comment: The hadith is not only in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/54/136), but also quoted in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/39/31) and [Jami' at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/83) imam an-Nawawi quoted in his commentary al-Qadi 'Iyads saying that this ruling of estimating prayers is specific for that day. Some others said that on that day the time will not change, but we will get the feeling that the day is longer.

Answer (score 1):

There are different opinions on the matter, some Fuqahā' say for fasting and prayers you should follow your home country times. Some others say the nearest country in which the times of the five daily prayers can be distinguished (as Ansari pointed out).

Answer (score 1):

The [European council for fatwa and research](http://e-cfr.org/new/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%B1%D9%82%D9%85-3-2/) (ECFR) has given a fatwa on this very purpose:
Saying that one can combine maghrib an 'isha prayer in the summer (when days are long) and dhur and 'asr in winter

> حكم الجمع بين صلاتي المغرب والعشاء لتأخر وقت العشاء أو انعدام علامته الشرعية في بعض البلاد.
>
> انتهى المجلس إلى جواز الجمع بين هاتين الصلاتين في اوروبا في فترة الصيف
>   حين يتأخر وقت العشاء إلى منتصف الليل أو تنعدم علامته كلياً، دفعاً
>   للحرج المرفوع عن الأمة بنص القرآن، ولما ثبت من حديث ابن عباس في صحيح
>   مسلم:”أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم جمع بين الظهر والعصر، وبين المغرب
>   والعشاء من غير خوف ولا مطر. قيل لابن عباس: ما أراد إلى ذلك؟ قال: أراد
>   ألا يحرج أمته”. كما يجوز الجمع في تلك البلاد في فصل الشتاء أيضاً بين
>   الظهر والعصر لقصر النهار وصعوبة أداء كل صلاة في وقتها للعاملين في
>   مؤسساتهم إلا بمشقة وحرج. وينبه المجلس على أن لا يلجأ المسلم إلى الجمع
>   من غير حاجة، وعلى أن لا يتخذه له عادة.

And in Germany the local fiqh (?) council announced that this would be applied for the situation where 'isha' prayer time is later then 11 pm, but they -apparently- added that this is only applied for mosques, as the combination of prayers like this was only made in mosques (they apparently did qiyas for the matter if it was raining etc.). But personally I don't agree with this, as the fatwa of the ECFR is providing a general statement. Note that in my opinion and practice I have the feeling that about nobody takes care of the fatawa neither those of the ECFR nor the German council except a couple of mosques who seem to pin them as an announcement no more no less.

The fatwa is based on the hadith of ibn 'Abbass () quoted in [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/64), Sunan an-Nasaa-i, Sunan abi Dawod and Jami' at-Tirmidhi which is saying that the Messenger of Allah () combined prayers even when there was no fear nor rain (an addition that is not present in all versions of this hadith).