# How can I offer prayers near the Arctic circle in Alaska?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are praying times handled in countries with a long day light?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-are-praying-times-handled-in-countries-with-a-long-day-light)

A lot of people live near the arctic circle where the duration of daylight and night is in odd proportion. Take the example of Fairbanks, Alaska, for example. Notice that today, June 20, 2012. The sun sits at 12:47 pm and it rises at 2:57 am.

How can I offer prayers in these areas? What if I go to towns above the arctic cicle where a a typical sunny day can last as long as 14 days. I need guidance in both the situations.

[image]

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. Try searching before asking your question next time.

Comment: The original question is very general. Here I am asking near the arc circle where where days and night are still defined. The picture shows sun rise and sun sit.

Comment: @Crocodile - I'd argue that your question is too local ;)

Comment: @Swati, hahaha lets talk about finland, it is not local but legit.