# On what evidence did Sheikh Dr Usama Hasan issue his fatwa on fasting?

Tags: sawm, fatwa

In June 2015, Sheikh Dr Usama Hasan [issued a fatwa](https://unity1.wordpress.com/2014/06/30/fatwa-on-fasting-in-ramadan-during-the-uk-summer/) to reduce the fasting period of British Muslims during Ramadan. He said that if in your country, the period for fasting is 18 hours or more than you should fast normally but break it when Muslim in Makkah (Mecca) do it because it is too long to cope with.

What is his evidence that this is allowed in Islam?

Comment: I haven't read that fatwa, but I would guess he bases it on the same verse about ramadan: 2:185 , "وَلَا يُرِيدُ بِكُمُ الْعُسْرَ"
Could you add a reference to the fatwa at least?

Comment: Related post: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14813/ramadan-is-there-a-solution-to-long-summer-days

Comment: I don't think it is based on "straight" evidence. However, there are practical reasons for this. The closer you are to the poles, the longer the days are in summer. The polar circles are the lines where the longest day lasts for 24 hours. Inside it, you could die of thirst by waiting for sunset a for few 24h periods in a row. Any verse forbidding you to hurt yourself because of fasting can be used as evidence.