# Can we offer salat before it's time?

Tags: salat, fiqh

Salamualaikum

Sometimes we are in difficult situations where we cannot offer salat. For exemple I work in a company and I don't have enough time to go home, eat, offer salat azhur and then get back to work because I have to go out 10/20 mintes before the time of salat. Not to mention salat al Asr I don't have the time to offer it at all (ps : I live in Europe and the country where I live has severe issues with racism and muslims)

So can we offer salat before it's time ?

Comment: No, in extreme cases, you can offer Zuhr along with Asr, and Isha along with Maghrib. No more exceptions. You can shorten your prayers if you're travelling. If, your job is hindering you from offering your regular Salah in time, maybe you should think of a new job. Peace!

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do so at least not always or let it become a habit.
But what you can or -in this case- must do for sure is to do your prayers later (as qada'/qza'a) if the situation is as described!

Now i also live in Europe and some colleagues and sometimes even the boss could be understanding and you might have a room -or at least time to use your or a colleagues room - where you can do your prayers at a time or in your coffee/smoker break.

You have also the possibility to do the prayer as Ima' as I mentioned in my answer [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14475/praying-on-an-extended-flight).

And if you don't want to disturb that much you can apply [this hadith](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/64) which allows combining prayers even if there's neither fear nor rain. So you might pray for example at dhor and 'asr when the timing for dhor ends or the timing for 'asr begins and the same could be done for maghrib and 'isha' (see also [this post](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-are-praying-times-handled-in-countries-with-a-long-day-light)). But that shouldn't become a usual behavior, as we are more than strongly encouraged to pray on time (see for example [2:238](http://legacy.quran.com/2/238), [4:103](http://legacy.quran.com/4/103) and [103:1-2](http://legacy.quran.com/103/1-2)) and [in congregation](http://sunnah.com/malik/8/1)!

And Allah knows best!

Answer (score -3):

Allah never said your prayers are voided because you offer salat early so (Allahu’a’lam)!!!!

Comment: Your answer is too short. Include sources to found your views. In particular as you are here giving an answer that is not common consensus in Islam, you should try to be longer in your explanation although it is difficult to prove that something has *not* been said.

Comment: Allah said the prayers are related to times, so certainly what you say is in disagreement to the qur'an.