# Can I pray qaza salahs leaving Nafls and Ghair Mokada Sunnah as routine?

Tags: salat, sunni, hanafi, salat-qada, maliki

Can I offer qaza salahs leaving Nafls and Ghair-Mokada Sunnah of 5 time prayers as a routine or I must first offer complete salah including Nafls and Ghair-Mokada Sunnahs?

What is preferred way, answer must be in accordance with Sunni fiqh (Imam Abu Hanifa, Imam Malik, Imam Shafi or Imam Ahmad ibn Hanbal) who believe we must offer qaza salahs (i.e. Farz and Witr).

We do believe Allah with His blessing will compensate our qaza Farz by our Sunnahs and Nafl but isn't it better to cover qaza Farz by offering them when there is chance to offer them?

I have to offer many Qaza prayers and I want to create a routine to offer some qaza prayers with each of 5 five prayers.

Comment: First if you want answers of each madhab the answer would take more than a single post. Basically there are three views one saying you can't do qada' of very old prayers one saying you should one saying you should perform more nafl prayers instead. Leaving the sunan al mu'akada is not recommended. Please specify what you mean by qada' prayers is it a recent prayer you've missed or haven't you prayed for years.

Comment: Mazhab which say we should offer qaza salahs, I want to know what is their guidance about "Ghair-Mokada" sunnahs (should I prefer qaza salahs when I have too many to offer or not)

Comment: I've answered already questions on that topic or mentioned an answer ...

Comment: Than answer addresses leaving of Nafl and Sunnah for nothing. Please note in Hanfi fiqh it is recommended to offer more important Qaza leaving Nafl `[Durr-e-Mukhtar:Vol.1, Page: 536]`, I just have confusion left for Ghair-Mokada Sunnahs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radd_al-Muhtar_ala_al-Dur_al-Mukhtar

Comment: You posted a link on this page under an answer, that answer is removed now.

Comment: You can either mark a question duplicate or answer it, I can't search and track for answer among all of your answers on the site.

Comment: I guess it is much easier for you to check my answers on the salat-qada tag i can't do so as I'm actually only online via my mobile phone as I'm travelling these days.

Comment: Maybe you find your answer here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31079/what-do-i-do-if-i-missed-joined-prayers, here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25983/can-we-offer-salat-before-its-time or here http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25969/should-i-make-up-for-6-10-years-of-possibly-invalid-prayer-and-fasts