# Before my trip can I combine the Dhuhr with Asr?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings

Yeah, so tomorrow I’m going on a trip and I was wondering if I could combine my Dhuhr with Asr right before I leave because when I arrive to the other city it will be Maghrib.

Comment: You should first add an important information: When will you leave home if it is before Dhohr time you can't combine both prayers! As you are not allowd to pray prayers before it's time (this is somewhat relevant [can we offer salat before it's time?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25983/can-we-offer-salat-before-its-time/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Islamqa has answer for you:

> ... it is permissible for you to bring ‘Asr forward and pray it with Zuhr in your home city, if you think it most likely that you will not be able to pray it on time because of travelling.
>   <sub>[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/20017)</sub>

The answer is: "Yes. You can."

Comment: This answer needs elaboration just saying yes and quoting a fatwa out of context is misleading, as the question answered there is whether one can combine dhohr and 'asr shortly before the time of 'asr. One cannot pray dhohr and 'asr if one leaves home before the time of dhohr!