# Postponing salats due to time-critical issues

Tags: salat, salat-qada

As you may deduced from the title I'm a sunni living in Belgium, Europe. Sunnism is commonly regarded as a less orthodox muslim community than shiism (correct me if I'm wrong). One of the implications are that one postpones salats if there comes something in between him and him performing the salat like university or work. That's why I often pray Duhr, Asr and Maghreb together if I come home at 7.00 pm from university since I need to be there at 8.30 am. The reason why I stay so late at the university is because I can concentrate much better there than at home.

> I wonder why if my way of postponing salats is permissible or not?

Please elaborate your answer till you think you have provided everything you know on this matter and please link some references to it so that I can look all the elaborations of the authors myself.

LS: My apologies for the misspellling of the words since for some there isn't a consensus on how to write it properly because most write it phonetically.

Comment: If you have two questions, please put them as two separate questions. Also, I think there's probably too much context. Simply saying, "I frequently have to postpone salat because there are time-critical things I have to do, is this permissable?" would be fine.

Comment: @PointlessSpike That is fine by me.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I've reduced my original question by half. Is it better this way?

Comment: One day has passed and nobody answered my question. Is there something unclear?

Comment: Do I ask too much?

Comment: I'm afraid questions often go unanswered. But I've taken a look and there are answers to that question that might help. Basically, it seems that there's an allotted time and it's mandatory that it must be done in this time. I've done other research and no exceptions are mentioned.

Comment: About the first question-part there are answer like mine on https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/57/how-are-praying-times-handled-in-countries-with-a-long-day-light/30968#30968 which cover the situation in Europe and other northern or southern hemisphere countries which gives a legal status. Postponing while having the possibility to pray on time is at least disliked if not a sin.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I appreciate the reference link